# Is there anyway to find the value in a column that has multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to find the value in a column that has multiple value and return the name and ID from the dataframe.

Example DF

```
Name ID     N1       N2     N3     N4
John 354    1,2,4,5  4,5,6  7,8,9  1,2,4,5
Vane 444    4,3,     4,2,4  5,4,5  4,5,6
Lisa 654    1,3      5,6    5,6    2
Glen 454    1,3      6      7      8
```

For example I want to find if column N1:N4 have the value '2' and it will return the Name and ID

```
John , 354
Vane , 444
Lisa , 654
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUc using `str.contains` with `any`

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,'N1':].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('2')).any(1),['Name','ID']]
   Name   ID
0  John  354
1  Vane  444
2  Lisa  654
```